# Suave stops responding with "Socket failed to accept a client" error

Tags: f#, suave

I have an app running on AWS through ECS (as a Docker container) for which I used Suave to receive some REST commands.

The code is very primitive:

```
let conf =
    { defaultConfig with bindings = [ HttpBinding.createSimple HTTP "0.0.0.0" 80] }

let app =
    choose
        [
            POST >=> choose
                    [
                    path "/" >=> request (fun m ->
                        // find if this is a subscription confirmation
                        let isConfirmation =
                            m.headers |> List.exists (fun kvp -> snd kvp = "SubscriptionConfirmation")

                        ... more stuff here but that's it for the Suave code
```

and it is started with:

```
let listening, server = startWebServerAsync conf app
server    |> Async.Start
listening |> Async.RunSynchronously |> ignore // wait for the server to start listening
```

At least once a day, Suave stops replying to any request and I get the following in the log:

(this is a screenshot because I couldn't get the text log out of the (super annoying) AWS's logging UI)

[image]

The error is always the same, and this is an app in testing with very little traffic. However, it gets a ping message every 10s from another app.

Since this is my first Suave project, how can I troubleshoot this? is this a known problem? is there more logging I can do to help troubleshoot it? could the issue be due to docker itself?

---

Edit:

I decided to print the connections used every 1 min:

```
there are 9 connections open
there are 15 connections open
there are 21 connections open
there are 26 connections open
there are 32 connections open
there are 37 connections open
there are 43 connections open
there are 49 connections open
there are 55 connections open
there are 61 connections open
there are 67 connections open
```

There is a ping received, as a POST message, every 10 seconds.

I track it this way:

```
let p = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().GetTcpIPv4Statistics()
terminal.BroadcastMessage $"there are {p.CurrentConnections} connections open"
```

It looks like the connections never gets closed.

Comment: I'm dockerizing a Suave app and I've seen various other unexpected server errors already. I can't offer this as a response to your troubleshooting questions, but I'd recommend having a look at rewriting the entry point to ASP.NET Core app with https://github.com/giraffe-fsharp/Giraffe instead of Suave for the same API feel but much more battle-tested server implementation, if this approach is possible for you

Comment: @HonzaBrestan, I didn't know Giraffe, but since it's a small tool it may be a good idea to change webserver rather than troubleshooting this one. Unless someone comes up with an explanation about this problem.

Comment: Right, and Suave may be a be better fit for a small tool in general (avoiding using a larger framework), if you find a way to troubleshoot this. One thing that I think might help would be more information about the docker image/dockerfile - perhaps some defaults for the base image may need to be adjusted, or respected within the app. This sounds like some OS socket starvation issue

Comment: I would prefer suave for that reason, it's much smaller. I edited the question with more info: it looks like connections get created and never released so the OS effectively runs out of sockets.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. I started a Suave server like yours locally and POST'ed to it manually every few seconds. The connection count varies slightly over time, but doesn't climb. Can you tell us how your POST message is being sent? Is there any possibility that the client is holding the connection open?

Comment: I just printed the IPs of the incoming connections and sure enough, there are a lot of connections from IPs I do not know. I guess bots scanning the AWS public IP space. But I don't see the connections closing. I tried to return 'CLOSE' when I don't recognize the source but the connections remain open

Comment: It looks like your connection count is going up by 6 per minute, which corresponds to your pings, so my suspicion now is that this isn't caused by an outside source. I wonder if your client is using Keep-Alive, and opening a new connection each time?

Comment: Or client side may be shutting down its connections without the close handshake, which would leave the server with no way to know the connection should be thrown away. The detection timeouts and connection pings can be fine tuned to help fight this https://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/usingkeepalive.html, but I don't know if this is applicable to AWS ECS

Comment: @HonzaBrestan, it's interesting as a way to not keep the connections hanging, but since I'm using the ECS service from AWS, I don't have access to the host, I just provide docker images.

Comment: Alternative approach: it looks like Suave may not implement top level request timeout, but it can be added as a web part/filter: https://suave.io/suave.html#def:val%20Suave.Filters.timeoutWebPart. Would wrapping your API in `timeoutWebPart` help closing the connection automatically after the specified timeout? It may not help, depending how it handles request vs. its connection, but may be easy enough to try with maybe 30 sec timeout or something like that

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, that's definitely worth trying. I wasn't aware of that filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a guess, but I'm now able to reproduce this using PowerShell `Invoke-WebRequest` across multiple terminals. Each new terminal I open causes the number of open connections to increase. It turns out that `Invoke-WebRequest` uses a `Keep-Alive` header by default, so I was able to fix the problem by disabling this feature.

Thus, I'm wondering if perhaps your client (the thing sending the ping) is using a keep-alive header, but failing to reuse the connections it opens. If so, you could fix this by disabling keep-alive in the client.

Comment: I can talk to the client team, but I don't have full control on what they do. In the worst case, would using CLOSE forcefully close the connection?

Comment: I just try to force close their connection and the problem seems to have disappeared, so now I have a solution and I can try to get them to fix things on their side.