# Suave runs out of sockets when receiving messages from AWS' SNS service

Tags: f#, suave

This is linked to question: [Suave stops responding with "Socket failed to accept a client" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66734192/suave-stops-responding-with-socket-failed-to-accept-a-client-error)

When I first started to use Suave, I was taking commands from a 3rd party service pushing messages and I would have an out of socket situation.

There is now more understanding of the problem:

I am receiving messages that are posted to the SNS service on AWS (it's just a queue). SNS will forward me each message it receives through a HTTP connection, as a POST message.

If I reply with Ok, I will run out of sockets. So this means that Suave is trying to keep the connection open and AWS is somehow initiating a new connection every time.

If I reply with CLOSE, the AWS' delivery starts to become odd and messages get delivered in batches followed by periods of nothing.

Since AWS will not change their system for me, I'm wondering if I can reply Ok but then somehow close the connection in Suave to not run out of sockets. Is it possible?

Or, is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Did you determine whether they are sending a keep-alive header?

Comment: @brianberns, yes, I just confirmed: headers: [["accept-encoding","gzip,deflate"],["user-agent","Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"],["connection","Keep-Alive"],["host","18.180.86.252"],["content-type","text/plain; charset=UTF-8"],["content-length","1219"],["x-amz-sns-subscription-arn","arn:aws:sns:ap-northeast-1:xxxxx"],["x-amz-sns-topic-arn","arn:aws:sns:ap-northeast-1:xxxxxx:x"],["x-amz-sns-message-id","xxxxxxxxxx"],["x-amz-sns-message-type","Notification"]]